# How to turn off landscape orientation in custom iOS App Extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, ios-app-extension

I have a custom iOS App Extension and I am unable to turn off landscape orientation when the device is rotated.

I need the app extension to stay in portrait mode.

The app extension ignores -preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation and obviously does not inherit from my base app.

Comment: App extensions are at the mercy of their host application.  You have no real control outside of your root UIView.

Comment: So is it not possible? I see it's also impossible to change status bar text to white. Well done Apple.

Comment: I know you're being sarcastic, so I'll just point out that your extension is a guest within another app.  Think about how you'd feel getting bug reports from users of your app, complaining that the status bar goes white-on-white for no reason (users usually don't correlate their actions to the observed bug) or just disappears.

Comment: I'm using a custom share extension, so it takes up the whole screen. So the status bar text can hardly be seen on my dark background colour (to keep with the theme of my app). I do need the extension to be presented in portrait mode only though.

Comment: That's irrelevant.  Your code is still running in another app, and if you change the status bar, nothing is forcing you to change it back.  Also, keep in mind that Apple is always conservative with respect to how apps can change the system.  This extends naturally into limiting how extensions can affect the host app.  Perhaps someday Apple will come up with a clever way of letting the extension specify these things.

Comment: (continued) Remember that extensions, the idea of running code under some other app, is fairly new in and of itself.

Comment: I understand that, but, Apple could have a done a better job or taken the same approach as Android. They could easily have made app extensions a separate state that return to their default when finished. But thanks for replying, so just to confirm - I cannot lock in portrait only mode in a custom app extension?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't been doing iOS for very long.  Apple is a very conservative company in some ways.  They move slowly because they have a different focus than you, as a developer, have.

Answer (score 1):

why don't set it via app plist?

if you prefer extension, please also set `shouldAutorotate` to return NO.

Comment: Actually it didn't work, I don't know why it temporarily did. In the plist I set Support interface orientations to Portrait (bottom home button) only, and I also set shouldAutorotate to return NO. Still no luck? Is this even possible in an extension?

Comment: I am having this problem now! Did u find any solution @Chicken?

Comment: I ended up having to support both orientations unfortunately. Not sure if there's a way now, I just gave in :(